# C++ How to return an array from a function?

Tags: c++, arrays, dynamic-memory-allocation, dynamic-arrays

I'm brand new to C++ and am having trouble trying to get a function (which takes an array) to return an array. The function is a very basic sorting algorithm for an array of integers of size 4. What i have is below:

```
int[] sortArrayAscending(int arrayToSort[3]) {
    int sortedArray[3];
    sortedArray[0] = minOfFour(arrayToSort[0],arrayToSort[1],arrayToSort[2],arrayToSort[3]);
    sortedArray[1] = lowerMidOfFour(arrayToSort[0],arrayToSort[1],arrayToSort[2],arrayToSort[3]);
    sortedArray[2] = higherMidOfFour(arrayToSort[0],arrayToSort[1],arrayToSort[2],arrayToSort[3]);
    sortedArray[3] = maxOfFour(arrayToSort[0],arrayToSort[1],arrayToSort[2],arrayToSort[3]);
    return sortedArray;
}
```

I think i'm getting really confused with the syntax i need to use (the function calls to min, lower, higher, max all work fine.

I would really appreciate some help.

Thank you

EDIT2: Thank you for all the comments. I have now solved it thanks to @Rook's and @Bob Yoplait's answers. The code is used is:

```
   int* sortArrayAscending(int arrayToSort[4], int sortedArray[4]) {
    sortedArray[0] = minOfFour(arrayToSort[0],arrayToSort[1],arrayToSort[2],arrayToSort[3]);
    sortedArray[1] = lowerMidOfFour(arrayToSort[0],arrayToSort[1],arrayToSort[2],arrayToSort[3]);
    sortedArray[2] = higherMidOfFour(arrayToSort[0],arrayToSort[1],arrayToSort[2],arrayToSort[3]);
    sortedArray[3] = maxOfFour(arrayToSort[0],arrayToSort[1],arrayToSort[2],arrayToSort[3]);
    return sortedArray;
}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    int testNumbers[4] = {8,14,1,27};
    int testSorted[4];
    sortArrayAscending(testNumbers,testSorted);

    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        cout << testSorted[i] << endl;
    }

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Thank you for all your help - now time to lookup vectors!

PS I appreciate @Luchian Grigore's solution is most likely the best practise way of doing things, but that wasn't specifically my question

Comment: Use a `std::vector<int>` instead.

Comment: if you have C++11, use `std::array<int,4>`.

Comment: All the array or vector sizes should be 4, not 3.

Comment: *"The problem [..] asks for arrays"?* Is this an assignment of some sort?

Comment: Do note that when you start using `new` you also have to use `delete`. By returning an `int*` make sure that someone deletes it! By using vectors you don't get this issue, because a copy is made to return the result (if I remember my C++ correctly..)

Comment: Your main now creates and leaks the array 4 times. Calculate it outside the loop and delete it after the loop.

Comment: You are currently calling the `sortArrayAscending` 4 times and you are not deleting any of the returned pointers that you have created. Please read up on the operator `new` before you continue..

Comment: You can read a bit about it [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6500313/in-c-why-should-new-be-used-as-little-as-possible)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Me, I'd probably use `std::array<int, 4>` if I was using a modern C++ compiler. Deals nicely with bounds checking and memory management and returning from/passing into functions. You can also use existing STL `sort` mechanisms and functions upon it; no need to reinvent the wheel!

Now, in your case,

```
int sortedArray[3];
```

is a local variable and you should **never** return a reference to it directly. You could do something like :

```
int* sortedArray = new int[4];
// do stuff
return sortedArray;
```

(also note the size of the array, 4, not 3 in your case!) but in this case you have to remember to delete the array at some point in the future or your application will leak memory.

You can also pass in the array by reference, using an approach like

```
void sort_array(std::array<int, 4>& the_array);
```

or

```
void sort_array(int** the_array)
```

and in these cases you can modify the array in place, or copy the answer into the argument when you're done sorting.

Comment: Thank you for the response - but c++ complains about "return sortedArray;" when i tried using "int* sortedArray = new int[4];" what is the correct return structure?

Answer (score 4):

EDIT: After your edit, you, your function returns a pointer to an array. Should work.

You can either return a pointer or a `std::vector`.

Note that in your code, you'd be running into undefined behavior, because `sortedArray` goes out of scope at the end of the method, and the memory is freed.

<del>I'd do this instead:</del>

```
std::vector<int> sortArrayAscending(int arrayToSort[4]) {
    std::vector<int> sortedArray(4);
    sortedArray.push_back( minOfFour(arrayToSort[0],arrayToSort[1],arrayToSort[2],arrayToSort[3]));
    sortedArray.push_back(  lowerMidOfFour(arrayToSort[0],arrayToSort[1],arrayToSort[2],arrayToSort[3]));
    sortedArray.push_back( higherMidOfFour(arrayToSort[0],arrayToSort[1],arrayToSort[2],arrayToSort[3]));
    sortedArray.push_back( maxOfFour(arrayToSort[0],arrayToSort[1],arrayToSort[2],arrayToSort[3]));
    return sortedArray;
}
```

**Actually, I wouldn't.** I'd just use `std::sort` instead of creating my own function, but that's just me.

Comment: `out_of_bounds` for `arrayToSort[3]`

Comment: @Default bah - copy pasted :)

Comment: yup, I understand. Although that is probably one of the OPs issues as well. Wouldn't it be good to use `std::vector` for the argument as well?

Comment: I'd +1 this again for that last edit. There is clearly a better solution to the OPs problem here than the one used..

Comment: @Default seeing how this is likely an assignment, I can understand the motivation behind the question though :)

Answer (score 2):

You are returning pointer to local variable, which leads to **undefined behavior**.  `sortedArray` is statically allocated array with automatic storage duration, which means that memory where it resides is being freed once you leave the scope of the function.

You should allocate it dynamically by using `new[]` or even better: use `std::vector` instead. If you choose to allocate it by using `new[]`, don't forget to free it by calling `delete[]` when you don't need this memory anymore.

Also note that `int sortedArray[3];` declares an array of size of 3 elements indexed from `0` to `2`. If you access 4th element of the array whose size is 3 (if you access the memory *"past the last element of the array object"*), **the behavior is undefined** as well.

Answer (score 2):

As this is C++, suggest using a [`std::vector<int>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) instead:

```
std::vector<int> sortArrayAscending(int arrayToSort[3]) {    
    std::vector<int> sortedArray(4); // Note 4, not 3.
    sortedArray[0] = ...;
    sortedArray[1] = ...;
    sortedArray[2] = ...;
    sortedArray[3] = ...;

    return sortedArray;
}
```

Note there are several [algorithms](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm) already available that will perform some of the tasks that you *appear* to be performing:

- [`max_element()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/max_element)
- [`min_element()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/min_element)

Answer (score 1):

Use Boost::Array (or std::array in C+11) that provides proper value semantic to C array.

```
boost::array<int,4> sortArrayAscending(boost::array<int,4>7 arrayToSort) 
{
    boost::array<int,4> sortedArray;
    sortedArray[0] = minOfFour(arrayToSort[0],arrayToSort[1],arrayToSort[2],arrayToSort[3]);
    sortedArray[1] = lowerMidOfFour(arrayToSort[0],arrayToSort[1],arrayToSort[2],arrayToSort[3]);
    sortedArray[2] = higherMidOfFour(arrayToSort[0],arrayToSort[1],arrayToSort[2],arrayToSort[3]);
    sortedArray[3] = maxOfFour(arrayToSort[0],arrayToSort[1],arrayToSort[2],arrayToSort[3]);
    return sortedArray;
}
```

Comment: `out_of_bounds` for `arrayToSort[3]`

Comment: well, it was faulty in the OPs example as well, the argument passed in only has 3 elements, not 4. So there is still an issue here.

Answer (score 1):

It is not like in Java

Either you pass sortedArray as a parameter to the func

```
int* sortArrayAscending(int* arrayToSort, int* sortedArray) {
    sortedArray[0] = minOfFour(arrayToSort[0],arrayToSort[1],arrayToSort[2],arrayToSort[3]);
    sortedArray[1] = lowerMidOfFour(arrayToSort[0],arrayToSort[1],arrayToSort[2],arrayToSort[3]);
    sortedArray[2] = higherMidOfFour(arrayToSort[0],arrayToSort[1],arrayToSort[2],arrayToSort[3]);
    sortedArray[3] = maxOfFour(arrayToSort[0],arrayToSort[1],arrayToSort[2],arrayToSort[3]);
    return sortedArray;
}

void toto() {
  int array[4]; // and fill values...
  int sortedArray[4];
  sortArrayAscending(array, sortedArray);
}
```

or

```
int* sortArrayAscending(int* arrayToSort) {
    int* sortedArray = new int[4];
    sortedArray[0] = minOfFour(arrayToSort[0],arrayToSort[1],arrayToSort[2],arrayToSort[3]);
    sortedArray[1] = lowerMidOfFour(arrayToSort[0],arrayToSort[1],arrayToSort[2],arrayToSort[3]);
    sortedArray[2] = higherMidOfFour(arrayToSort[0],arrayToSort[1],arrayToSort[2],arrayToSort[3]);
    sortedArray[3] = maxOfFour(arrayToSort[0],arrayToSort[1],arrayToSort[2],arrayToSort[3]);
    return sortedArray;
}
```

and then you need to delete the returned array in the second case.

Answer (score 0):

Arrays are always passed by reference to any function in C++.
So, just pass your array to the function. Your original array would get sorted and you can then use it in your program. I believe there is no need to return the array explicitly.